# Strange \foreach[evaluate] behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm getting strange behavior when using TikZ's *evaluate* syntax.

[image: Why is the bottom line shorter than the other three?]

See how the bottom diagonal line is shorter than the other three? This is not the desired behavior. The code for the above image is here:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (X\x) at (0,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (Y\x) at (3,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
% start weirdness
    \draw (X0) -- (Y1);
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using \x+1] in {1,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
    }
% end weirdness. 
% Comment out the above weirdness and uncomment out the following:
%   \draw (X0) -- (Y0);
%   \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using \x] in {1,...,3}
%   {
%      \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
%   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you comment out the lines between "start weirdness" and "end weirdness" and you un-comment out the last five lines, you'll see that the problem is magically fixed: all the lines look the same.

[image: Now all the lines are the same length.]

Again, in the original code---and the associated picture at the top of this post---the desired behavior is the shorter line. The other three are undesirable. Can you help me get the desired behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to wrap `\x+1` into `int`, `\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using {int(\x+1)}] in {1,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
    }`, since otherwise you get numbers like `2.0`, where `.0` is interpreted as an anchor.

Comment: wow, thanks! If you write that as an answer, I'll select it, thus giving you points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in my comment, you need to wrap `\x+1` into `int`

```
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using {int(\x+1)}] in {1,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
    }
```

since otherwise you get numbers like `2.0`, where `.0` is interpreted as an anchor. `.0` is (in this case) coincident with the east anchor, i.e. at angle 0. Your output shows lines that connect to the east anchor of the respective `Y`-type nodes. You may wonder why the problem does not happen in the second loop. This is because when you say

```
 evaluate=\x as \sx using \x
```

Ti*k*Z does not need to parse the expression, and does not add `.0`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (X\x) at (0,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (Y\x) at (3,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
% start weirdness
    \draw (X0) -- (Y1);
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using {int(\x+1)}] in {1,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}   
\quad\mbox{vs.}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
% end weirdness. 
% Comment out the above weirdness and uncomment out the following:
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (X\x) at (0,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (Y\x) at (3,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
  \draw (X0) -- (Y0);
  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using \x] in {1,...,3}
  {
     \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I would avoid using `\x` as the loop variable since it is also used by `calc`, i.e. you may find other "weirdness" if you use `calc` with `\x` loops. And if you want the gaps to go away, you could just draw the nodes with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}]
    \path foreach \Y in {0,...,4} 
        {(0,\Y) node[bullet] (X\Y){}
         (3,\Y) node[bullet] (Y\Y) {}
        };
    \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+1)}] in {0,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\X) -- (Y\Y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}   
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Steven B. Segelets suggests to use `\the\numexpr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519114/194703). This works fine but then you do not need `evaluate` at all.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}]
    \path foreach \Y in {0,...,4} 
        {(0,\Y) node[bullet] (X\Y){}
         (3,\Y) node[bullet] (Y\Y) {}
        };
    \foreach \X  in {0,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\X) -- (Y\the\numexpr\X+1);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}   
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a `tikz` way of doing it, but I concluded the `\x+1` needed evaluation, so since it is integral, I used `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (X\x) at (0,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
    \foreach \x in {0,...,4} 
        {\node (Y\x) at (3,\x) {$\bullet$};
        }
% start weirdness
    \draw (X0) -- (Y1);
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using \the\numexpr\x+1\relax] in {1,...,3}
    {
        \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
    }
% end weirdness. 
% Comment out the above weirdness and uncomment out the following:
%   \draw (X0) -- (Y0);
%   \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \sx using \x] in {1,...,3}
%   {
%      \draw (X\x) -- (Y\sx);
%   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]