# Error with length of list of listofitems and ... in \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, listofitems

While I was answering [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621554/connect-points-in-array-with-foreach), I found the error

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

only when I use `...` in a `\foreach` with a simple operation of the list length:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{;}

\begin{document}

\readlist\points{(1,2); (2,3); (3,2); (1,1); (2,2)}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,2,3,4}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,...,4}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,2,3,\pointslen-1}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}

This gives the error 
\texttt{! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,...,\pointslen-1}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure where the actual problem is (though my guess is in the `\foreach` limits evaluator), but enclosing the suspect term in `\numexpr...\relax` (to evaluate an integer) fixes it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{;}

\begin{document}

\readlist\points{(1,2); (2,3); (3,2); (1,1); (2,2)}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,2,3,4}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,...,4}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,2,3,\pointslen-1}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}

%This gives the error 
%\texttt{! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,...,\numexpr\pointslen-1\relax}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Steven! I wait a bit before accepting to see if someone knows the exact reason.

Comment: @CarLaTeX The current behavior reminds me of this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519113/strange-foreachevaluate-behavior.  Maybe related...(or not)

Comment: @CarLaTeX To show it has nothing to do with `listofitems`, one gets the same error result with the syntax: `\def\tmp{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {1,...,\tmp-1}
        {\draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Thanks, I leave out the `listofitems` tag.

Comment: I tried with `int(...)` even with an evaluate but I didn't manage to solve the problem as you did.

Answer (score 5):

The last item in the specification of the range for `\foreach` has to be an integer. Also

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,5-1} {...}
```

would fail with the same error. To the contrary, `\numexpr\pointslen-1\relax` will work.

An `expl3` implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\definelist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_carlatex_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_split:cnn { l_carlatex_list_#1_seq } { ; } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { c }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlistitem}{mm}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { l_carlatex_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getlistlen}{m}
 {
  \seq_count:c { l_carlatex_list_#1_seq }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\definelist{points}{(1,2); (2,3); (3,2); (1,1); (2,2)}

This works:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i  in {1,...,\inteval{\getlistlen{points}-1}} {
    \draw \getlistitem{points}{\i} -- \getlistitem{points}{\i+1};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg, but why does `\foreach \i  in {1,2,3,\pointslen-1}`  work?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Because in that case PGF does not need to do any computations of the numbers it has to use and just takes one item after the other.

Comment: Thank you, understood.

Comment: Eventually, I accepted Steven's answer because he used `\numexpr...\relax` first.